# Symfony serializer returns string instead of float

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

How can the Symfony Serializer Component be configured to normalize a float property of an object (entity)?

In detail: the `taxRate` property of a doctrine entity is is mapped to a PHP float value. And I would like to respond from a controller with a JSON representation like:

```
{taxRate:0.19}
```

But what I get is

```
{taxRate:"0.19"}
```

The definition of the entity's property and annotations are:

```
class ExampleEntity {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2, nullable=true)
   * @Groups({"api"})
   */
  protected $taxRate;
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
return new JsonResponse(
  $serializer->normalize(
    $exampleEntity,
    'json',
    [
      'groups' => 'api',
    ]
  )
);
```

I don't like the solution of converting the string into a Float on the JavaScript side. My app would like to assert the property is NULL or a Float value.

How can this be done?

Comment: try `type="float"`

Comment: @sietse85 `type="float"` would be the doctrine orm mapping configuration ... which is not taken into account by the symfony serializer.

Comment: Seriously? I tried it and it works.But 1. Where is this documented? Because that annotation is for Doctrine, right? 2. I thought DECIMAL is more safe to use, because the MySQL FLOAT type needs the PHP locale to use '.' as a floating point delimiter which is not always the case. 3. Thank you! 4. Is there a way to stick to DECIMAL and achieve a conversion to float/double? (That's what I always thought)

Comment: @nifr you are right. But thanks to sietse85' s comment I realized that the "wrong" convesion happens prior to the serialization. I did not know DECIMAL gets mapped/converted to PHP strings. My fault. Now I am a little unhappy with that fact :)

Comment: Good catch. You could use the `GetSetMethodNormalizer` with `public function getTaxRate(): float { return (float)$this->taxRate; }` and `public function setTaxRate($taxRate) { $this->taxRate = (float)$taxRate; }` to prevent these issues with conversion.

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotation @var float to that class property? I don't know if that would hint the serializer at all about the variables type

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I think the question is not very clear/can be removed.

The serialization process is fine, it's the mapping from Doctrine which I did not get right.

It is totally OK, DECIMAL Doctrine/MySQL types are mapped to PHP strings.
DECIMAL is designed to guarantee a precision for a numeric value. PHP's float type cannot guarantee the same precision.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Symfony 4.4 serializer, and I disagree with your solution. I resolved my problem by changing type="decimal" to type="float", as some people already suggested it in the comments. A proper type hinting is a good practice. Why using a string when you can use a float?

**Float type, from doctrine documentation :**

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.12/reference/types.html#types

> Maps and converts numeric data with floating-point precision. If you
> only need an approximate precision for numbers with fractions, you
> should consider using this type. Values retrieved from the database
> are always converted to PHP's float/double type or null if no data is
> present.

**Some additionnal information about this approach :**

- Symfony serializer does read your ORM annotations if you instantiate it well using a service container
- Symfony serializer is perfectly abble to consider floats as floats
- Doctrine needs a precision for a float, PHP doesn't, and it's totally OK. You can insert a float in your database, Doctrine will round it if necessary.

**A float attribute example for the serializer :**

```
/**
 * @var float|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", precision=6, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
protected $ratio;

/**
 * @return float|null
 */
public function getRatio(): ?float
{
    return $this->ratio;
}

/**
 * @param float|null $ratio
 * @return $this
 */
public function setRatio(?float $ratio): self
{
    $this->ratio = $ratio;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **decimal** type values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP's string type or null if no data is present.

[Doctrine Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#decimal)

If you want to use decimal, change the getter for property

```
public function getTaxRage(): ?float
{
    return is_string($this->taxRate) ? (float) $this->taxRate : $this->taxRate;
}
```